# Building a Dynamic UI with Fragments with custom UI elements

Tags: android, android-fragments, dynamic-ui

Okay so I have a question regarding building a dynamic UI with Fragments. Been working through the developer documents of Android and I have a question which I cannot seem to find an answer to or don't know how to search for it.

I want to create a fragment at runtime, so from what I read I need to have a FrameLayout which will act as my container for my fragment that I want to add. For this to work I need to (at compile time) define the fragments that will be active during my application that I want to swap in and out of. But here is my question, what if I don't know what these fragments will look like at compile time? What if I want to dynamically change the way they look at runtime?

So basically what I want to be able to do is load a fragment and then in the onCreateView() define which UI elements it needs to display (text views, edit texts and radio buttons), I then want to press a button and load another fragment (replacing the current one) where I then again in the onCreateView() define which UI elements I want to display. But upon navigating to the next fragment I want to add the current one with the custom UI elements I just added, to the backstack so that the user can navigate back to it later. I want to navigate through about 10 or more of these custom UI elements fragments, saving all the previous ones to a back stack.

Can this be done using fragments? From what I can see I need to define the Fragment.java file which the activity loads at compile time, which means that I need to have predefined ones before I start? How then do I do what I want to achieve?

So I guess part of what I want to know is can I create Fragments dynamically at runtime and not at compile time? I don't just want to load different already created Fragments, I actually want to create them once the app is already running, give them a custom interface by adding UI elements after I create them and then be able to add those to the back stack to navigate back to later.

I really hope this makes sense.

Thanks,
Wihan

Comment: I don't get it. If you don't specify any UI at compile time, where does it come from at runtime? Do you want to create a UI while in the app? Maybe use WebView and show your UI in it.

Comment: At runtime I get a file from a server that says my UI must have the following elements (text views, radio buttons, edit texts). I then need to load a blank activity and add all those elements to the activity for the user to interact with, so they all need to be created dynamically. The server can say I need 50 elements, so then I need to show like 3 on the screen, press a button and show the next 3 and so on. So every single item must be drawn at runtime, so I need to know if I can do this with a fragment and save each custom screen to the backstack so that the user can navigate back to it?

Comment: The fragment UI can be loaded from an XML file, so there is no problem, if you want to you can put fragment transactions on the backstack, so that's possible too. I think you should just try and see how far you get and then come back when there is a real programming problem. Then we can help you better.

Comment: @ElDuderino I think you miss understand what I am trying to achieve here. I have no XML file other than a blank layout in which to put my fragment (the blank layout will be part of the activities layout with an empty FrameLayout as the container for the fragment), I then also have no .java fragment file defined at compile time. The appilcation needs to build all of this at runtime, so I am trying to find a way to do this with fragments while still being able to add to the back stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a way to create these fragments dynamically once the application is already running.

I had a look at the FragmentStack example in the APIDemos. This seems to be doing what I need to and want to do, still have to add all the custom UI elements, but the main functionality seems to be there. Has anyone else used it for this purpose?